# How can I get a Colony to Surrender instead of destroying it?

Tags: spore

I am space stage right now and sometimes when I laser or bomb cities on a planet sometimes they will surrender, but other times they will just blow up. This gets annoying when I want to capture a whole planet.

Is there a specific way to make them surrender instead of destroying them? And if so how do I do it?

Comment: Oops, I just realised that there is another question like this.